# Random forest classifier result from Predict_proba() does not match with predict()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, text-classification

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
pipeline = Pipeline([
('features', FeatureUnion([
    ('Comments',Pipeline([
        ('selector',ItemSelector(column = "Comments")),
        ('tfidf',TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False,ngram_range=(1,2),max_df=0.95, min_df=0,sublinear_tf=True)),
    ])),
    ('Vendor', Pipeline([
        ('selector',ItemSelector(column = "Vendor Name")),
        ('tfidf',TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False)),

    ]))
])),
('clf',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators =200, max_features='log2',criterion = 'entropy',random_state = 45))
 #('clf',LogisticRegression())
 ])


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                df['code Description'],
                                test_size = 0.3, 
                                train_size = 0.7,
                                random_state = 100)
model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
s = pipeline.score(X_test,y_test)
pred = model.predict(X_test)
predicted =model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

for some of classification my `predict` is matching with prediction score. but in some cases,

```
proba_predict = [0.3,0.18,0.155]
```

but instead of classifying it as class A, it is classifying as Class B.

Predict class: B

Actual Class : A

Right side column is my labels and left side column is my input text data:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data where this happens? With the provided information we cannot reproduce your results and cannot help.

Comment: @RafaelC No , I am telling there is some mismatch in result form predic_proba() and predict(). max of predict_proba() corresponding to the class should be my prediction but it is showing second highest as my prediction.

Comment: Is it worth double checking that `model.classes_` has classes in the same order you anticipate?

Comment: Yae , I am checking it from the scratch , As according to the source code it should predict max only. Thanks @Merlin1896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you state the following situation: For a test vector `X_test` you find a predicted probability distribution y=[p1, p2, p3] from the `predict_proba()` method with p1>p2 and p1>p3 but the `predict()` method does not output class 0 for this vector.

If you inspect the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L518) of the `predict` function of sklearn's `RandomForestClassifier`, you will see that the `predict_proba()` method of the RandomForest is called there:

```
proba = self.predict_proba(X)
```

From these probabilities, the `argmax` is used to output the class.

Hence, the prediction step uses the `predict_proba` method for its output. For me it seems impossible that anything goes wrong there.

I would assume that you mixed up some class names in your routine and got confused there. But it is not possible to give a more detailed answer based on the information you provided.

Comment: Hi @Merlin1896 I'm trying to write a wrapper for random forest regressor. So I tried typing self.predict_proba = super.predict_proba(X) but this gives an error saying super has no attribute predict_proba, which by the way is random forest regressor class

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu Please ask a new question with code samples!

Comment: Can I take you here? @Merlin1896

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697980/making-random-forest-outputs-like-logistic-regression