# Generating adversarial data from cleverhans attack models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, cleverhans

I want a code example to how to generate train data from clever hans' adversarial attacks.

```
adv_x = fgsm.generate_np(X_test, **fgsm_params)
```

This generates adversarial x data but how can I get y?

```
adv_pred = model.predict_classes(adv_x)
```

And this will give the "fooled" results right?

What I want is to correctly show generated x, y, fooled y (by which I mean results of models predictions that may be false because of the attack). I'm using Mnist btw, if it helps.

Comment: @NicolasPapernot May I have your wisdom?:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code snippets you shared, I would make two suggestions:

- It is generally not a good idea to train the model on test data (if you are going to use that test data to evaluate its performance afterwards) so I would replace `X_test` by `X_train` in your first line.
- To get the label for your adversarial examples, you can use the original labels of the training data or the predictions of the model on the original training data `model.predict_classes(X_train)` (this assumes that the adversarial example is not perturbed enough to change the label of the input).

Comment: So `adv_x = fgsm.generate_np(X_train, **fgsm_params)` is my x ####


y_train is already my y that belongs to perturbed adv_x #####


`adv_pred  = model.predict_classes(adv_x)` is my fooled results right?

Comment: I believe that's correct yes (not sure what the #### stands for though).

Comment: Thanks nicolas, you're a great guy:D